# Is there a way to extract name of case of CodingKeys enum?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to access the `CodingKeys` enum case's name. The only thing I can access to is its `stringValue`. I need to know the name because I comparing it to the variable name in the Decodable object. And sometimes the `stringValue` and the actual name is different.

I am aware that I could manually write a variable that would return the name of each case...but that wouldn't be scalable as it would make the models have unnecessary amount of boiler plate code.

This is basic example where the `name` is different from the `stringValue`. 
I need to somehow extract the `name`.

```
@objcMembers
class User: Decodable {
    dynamic var name: String = ""

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "user_name"
    }
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand why you need this, the name of the variable in the object to decode is obviously "user_name"?

Comment: Please show a realistic use case.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a instance of your enum, you can convert it's name to string like this:

```
let myEnum : CodingKeys = .name
let stringRepresentation = "\(myEnum.self)"
print(stringRepresentation) //this will print "name" on the console
```

Comment: unfortunately it prints `CodingKeys(stringValue: "user_name", intValue: nil)`

Comment: Hmm.. It's because you have the two 'types' `String, CodingKey`, if you remove the `CodingKey` it will work. But if you need that, maybe you can create a custom type String and CodingKey that conforms to  RawRepresentable and use it as the type of your enum